# How to access keywords recorded in a Lucene index?

Tags: java, search, lucene, keyword

I've got an EDM (electronic document management / archiving) working with Lucene (Java + Hibernate + Spring + JSF + Lucene).
Files treated have different formats : XML, DOCX, JPEG, INDD, PDF, etc.
All are archived after a full text indexation.

Searchs can be done thanks to a web page : users fill keywords and Lucene + Hibernate show all the documents that have been indexed containing those keywords.

What I would like is to know all the keywords indexed by Lucene in order to make possible users' subscribing for keywords they're interested in.

Actually, if a user wants to know all the documents with "France" keyword, he 'll have to make a search on the web page.
What I want is the user to subscribe for the "France" keyword and when a document with this keyword will be indexed the user will receive a notification telling him what documents contain the keyword he has subscribed to.

But I just don't know how to look up the Lucene index neither to detect that the Lucene's count for a given keyword has changed.

Can someone tell me how to do that ?

Thanx.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to rerun the search on all subscribed-to keywords each time the indexation process is run?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Map containing all terms in the index, mapped to the number of documents they appear in. Beware however that

1. That lucene's terms can hardly be considered keywords.
2. That this map will get quite large, depending on the size of your index.

Depending on your data, you will probably need to select the *n* best terms/keywords, either manually or by some algorithm (e.g. the 20 most frequent terms).

```
IndexReader reader = ..... // Open your index

// Create a new HashMap, mapping Terms to doc frequency
Map<String,Integer> allTerms = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

// Iterate over all fields of your documents
Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
for (String field : fields) {
    Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
    TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();

    // Iterate over all terms for the current field
    for(BytesRef br = termsEnum.next(); br != null; br = termsEnum.next()) {
        // Put the term and the number of occurrences into the map.
        allTerms.put(br.utf8ToString(), termsEnum.docFreq());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @philipp-ludwig 
I didn't test it yet (it's quiet late in France) but it is very interesting to discover a way to question the dictionary.
I understand all terms are not "readable" because they are tokens/chunks of words.

Comment: I'll have to find a way to select the most pertinent ones that are not the most frequent ones !!
One thing that remains difficult is to detect a change in the dictionary itself. Is there a way to trigger an alert when words are added in the dictionary ? How can we see something has changed?

Comment: Well, you will probably have to re-build the map again after you add a document and check for any differences between the old and the new version.